# How to check during Nokogiri/Ruby parsing if element exists on page?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

how can I check during parsing of an HTML page with Nokogiri (Ruby gem) if an element, in this case a div, exists on the page?

On my test page, it does exist, so the pp yields the expected Nokogiri output. But the if statement does not work, the == true seems to be the wrong way to go about it. Any suggestions for improvement? Cheers, Chris

```
pp page.at('.//div[@class="errorMsg"]')

if page.at('.//div[@class="errorMsg"]') == true then
    puts "Error message found on page"
end
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Comparing with `true` isn't the right way to go. The [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) call will return `nil` if it doesn't find anything so:

```
if page.at_css('div.errorMsg')
  puts 'Error message found on page'
else
  puts 'No error message found on page'
end
```

is one way as `nil` is falsey in a boolean context but a [`Nokogiri::XML::Node`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) won't be. I also switched to [CSS notation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) as I find that clearer than XPath for simple things like this but you're free to use [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) or feed XPath or a CSS selector to `at` if you like that better.

Also, the three `at` methods return the first matching element or `nil` so they're good choices if you just want to check existence.